# Assign value in Data Frame Column without Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame (below is only the subset):

| Data1 | Data2 | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | False |
| 2 |  | True |
| 5 |  | True |

I would like to put a value(string) in column Data2 = "Done" if the Status = True (boolean).

My code is:

```
d = {"Data1":[1,2,5], "Data2":["","",""], "Status": [False, True, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)


for x in range(len(df["Status"])):
     if df["Status"].loc[x] == True:
        df["Data2"].loc[x] = "Done"
     else:
        df["Data2"].loc[x] = ""
```

This code works. My question is: is there any way to do it without loop?

Comment: `df['Data2'] = np.where(df['Status'], 'Done', '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Numpy (just one line of code):

```
import numpy as np
df['Data2'] = np.where(df['Status'], 'Done', '')
```

The syntax is:

```
np.where(<criteria>, <value if criteria met>, <value if criteria not met>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.  Pandas indexing can use an array of booleans to select items.

```
df.loc[df["Status"]==True,"Data2"] = "Done"
df.loc[df["Status"]==False,"Data2"] = ""
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"Data1": [1, 2, 5], 
     "Data2": ["", "", ""], 
     "Status": [False, True, True]} df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def update_data2(row):
    return "Done" if row["Status"] else ""

df["Data2"] = df.apply(update_data2, axis=1)
```